# BMI classification structure

Tags: c

I am working on an assignment in C where I have to read in multiple people's heights and weights and determine their bmi. I then classify them into their respective bmi categories, but I am getting stuck on how to do this properly, this is my code thus far:

```
# include <stdio.h>

int main () {

    int people;
    double bmi, weight, inches;

            printf("How many peoples? > ");
            scanf("%d", &people);

    do {
            printf("Enter height (inches) and weight (lbs) (%d left) > ", people);
            scanf("%lf %lf", &inches, &weight);
            people--;
    }

    while (people > 0);

            bmi = (weight / (inches * inches)) * 703;

            if (bmi < 18.5) {
                    printf("Under weight: %d\n", people);
            }
            else if (bmi >= 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
                    printf("Normal weight: %d\n", people);
            }
            else if (bmi >= 25 && bmi < 30) {
                    printf("Over weight: %d\n", people);
            }
            else if (bmi >= 30) {
                    printf("Obese: %d\n", people);
            }
return 0;
}
```

where am i going wrong? where do i fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some data structure for storing data. You are getting input for more than one people but, finally processed for one person.

And also  `people--;` is done. so `people` variable is decremented up to zero, which makes `while` to exit without executing your BMI calculation.

**Modified Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_PEOPLE      100

int main () {

    int people;
    double bmi[MAX_PEOPLE], weight[MAX_PEOPLE], inches[MAX_PEOPLE];

    int index = 0;

            printf("How many peoples? > ");
            scanf("%d", &people);

    index = people;

    do {
            printf("Enter height (inches) and weight (lbs) (%d left) > ", index);
            scanf("%lf %lf", &inches[index], &weight[index]);
            index--;
    }while (index > 0);

        for(index = 0; index < people; index++)
        {

            bmi[index] = (weight[index] / (inches[index] * inches[index])) * 703;

            if (bmi[index] < 18.5) {
                    printf("Under weight: %d\n", index);
            }
            else if (bmi[index] >= 18.5 && bmi[index] < 25) {
                    printf("Normal weight: %d\n", index);
            }
            else if (bmi[index] >= 25 && bmi[index] < 30) {
                    printf("Over weight: %d\n", index);
            }
            else if (bmi[index] >= 30) {
                    printf("Obese: %d\n", index);
            }
        }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: do you recommend assigning another variable to represent "people--" something like y = people--;?

Comment: thanks! im going to use what you did and re-write my code just so i can be sure i fully understand it

Comment: so i was able to re-write the code using your example, but the output i need to get followed a certain way and i could not get it after working with it for a while, my output should look like this: Processed 3 people, and found:
Under weight: 0
Normal weight: 1
Over weight: 1
Obese: 1
Warning! The population may be unhealthy    where it actually prints all the 0's as well for the categories found, and then i add up the total value of overweight and obese and if that value is more than half of the total, then i print the warning

Comment: i just cant seem to figure out how to always store the data so i always have a print for each category, even if its zero, and then how to reference back to that data to be able to compare again to see if overall pop is overweight

Comment: This solution doesn't check that the value of people entered by the user fits in the array range defined by MAX_PEOPLE.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are processing the same data.

Each time you assign a new value to weight the old one is erased.

You could create multiple variables like so:

`double weight1, weight2, weight3, weight4,` ...etc (highly unpractical!!)
or
create an array of doubles:

```
double weight[100];
```

and refer to each specific double variable like this:

```
scanf("%lf %lf", inches[0], weight[0]);
scanf("%lf %lf", inches[1], weight[1]);
scanf("%lf %lf", inches[2], weight[2]);
```

You see where i-m getting at ? you can manipulate the array tru a **for loop**.

Comment: so i was able to re-write the code, but the output i need to get followed a certain way detailed below and i could not get it after working with it for a while, my output should look like this: Processed 3 people, and found: Under weight: 0 Normal weight: 1 Over weight: 1 Obese: 1 Warning! The population may be unhealthy where it actually prints all the 0's as well for the categories found, and then i add up the total value of overweight and obese and if that value is more than half of the total, then i print the warning, but i seem to only get print statements for the

Comment: people that are within that BMI range, ie, no "0 normal weight people" etc, i just cant seem to figure out how to always store the data so i always have a print for each category, even if its zero, and then how to reference back to that data to be able to compare again to see if overall pop is overweight, any help would be appreciated